# Google map is not visible in android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I used this code to show my location on map but map is not visible in app. App is running fine. I don't know what i am doing wrong. please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,OnMapReadyCallback{

GoogleMap mMap;
LatLng myPosition;

Location location;
LocationManager locationManager;
double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready      to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   // mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {




    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

    // getting GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // getting network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Is Off");

        alertDialog.setMessage("Please Enable GPS for better Location");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }

    {

        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 100f, this);

            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                }
            }
        }
        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 100f, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  /*  String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true).toString();
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 100.0f, this);
  //   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 10f, this);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);*/

//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),provider,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    // latitude = location.getLatitude();

//      longitude = location.getLongitude();


    myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition));

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 16));





    Timer t = new Timer(false);   //To show text for required time

    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    dialogbox();

                }
            });
        }
    }, 10000);


}
}
```

And also mMap.getMyType gives '1' value means normal map. But map is not  visible. Further I pass latitude and longitude value to another activity. In that activity it will print address of latitude and longitude provided. This part is working fine,it means app is  correctly locating my location but map is not visible.

Comment: Log your mapFragment if is is null or not.

Comment: Check your logcat for errors, usually it tells you what the problem is.